# Can you use ng-switch and ng-if together?

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was trying to use both the angular `ng-switch` and `ng-if` directives together, but it doesn't seem to be working. What I was doing was:

```
<div data-ng-if = "x === 'someValue'" data-ng-switch on = "booleanValue">
   <div data-ng-switch-when = "!booleanValue" data-ng-include="'partial/index.html'"></div>
   <div data-ng-switch-when = "booleanValue" data-ng-include="'partial/pageTwo.html'"></div>
</div>
```

I'm just wondering if that is possible or if there is an alternative way to switch those partials around based on some condition in the $scope?

Comment: Should the switch be `data-ng-switch on="..."` or `data-ng-switch="..."`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. It's supposed to be `data-ng-switch on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ng-switch-when, use `true` and `false` instead of `booleanValue` and `!booleanValue`:

```
<div data-ng-if = "x === 'someValue'" data-ng-switch on = "booleanValue">
   <div data-ng-switch-when = "false" data-ng-include="'partial/index.html'"></div>
   <div data-ng-switch-when = "true" data-ng-include="'partial/pageTwo.html'"></div>
</div>
```

You can also use ng-show:

```
<div data-ng-if = "x === 'someValue'" >
   <div data-ng-show = "!booleanValue" data-ng-include="'partial/index.html'"></div>
   <div data-ng-show = "booleanValue" data-ng-include="'partial/pageTwo.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Or just use ng-if again:

```
<div data-ng-if = "x === 'someValue'" >
   <div data-ng-if = "!booleanValue" data-ng-include="'partial/index.html'"></div>
   <div data-ng-if = "booleanValue" data-ng-include="'partial/pageTwo.html'"></div>
</div>
```

ng-if is closer to ng-switch, in that they both actually detach and reattach the html fragments from the DOM.  ng-show just toggles the visibility of the fragment without removing it from the DOM.